# Can I tell, from the browser, which Java version is installed, including whether OpenJDK, Oracle, etc

Tags: java, openjdk

I know of java.com/verity, but it only tells me the the version number of Java, e.g.

```
Your Java version: Version 8 Update 25
```

It does not tell me whether I have OpenJDK or Oracle installed. Is there another online service that does tell this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try [Java Plugin detector](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Java/)
2. Also **Java tester**

   [javatester.org](http://javatester.org/version.html)
3. Also don't forget the terminal -
   Run in the terminal:

   `java -version`
4. If you are using Firefox type **about: Plugins**.
   It will show your Java plugin being used:

[image]

Comment: javatester.org does not work for me, because I don't have the most recent version of Java. For security reasons.

Comment: The about:plugins worked well. However, if Oracle is installed, then it does not say Oracle anywhere. But I guess, when it does not say OpenJDK, then it's Oracle.

Comment: Regarding `java -version` in the terminal. The JVM run in the terminal is not necessarily the same as the one used by the browser, and in my case, they are different.